# How to update a nested JSON key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested JSON structure which will always have two keys by the name `top_nest` and `mid_nest`. However, at what level these two keys will be nested that may vary depending on the data set.

Each of top_nest and mid_nest has a 'remark' which is always null initially.
I want to populate that `remark` key with the value from an array.

Below is my code which I tried only for `mid_nest` key :

```
var nestedjson = {
  edition: '1.3.0',
  OUTER_MOST: {
    secondnest: {
      mainstruct: {
        top_nest: [
          {
            portblair: 'mtlb_wc_way0_fcl',
            dir: 'left',
            locs: ['/loc/local'],
            remark: 'crc',
            id: 1544593588899,
            $count: 0,
            $parent: 0,
            $level: 1,
            $height: 256,
          },
        ],

        mid_nest: [
          {
            ept: 'qop[3:0:0]',
            remark: null,
            race: 'false',
            spt: ['mki[2:7:21]', 'epk[20:14.2:9.8]'],
            inod: 'u_pqp',
            mlace: 'pqp',
            portblair: ['qq[31:9:24]', 'ax[2:16:1]'],
            marcus: [
              {
                dir: 'left',
                h_loc: ['/op/locs'],
                sign: '0',
                portblair_w: '81',
                race_duty: '0',
              },
              {
                race_duty: '0',
                portblair_h: '28',
                sign: '2',
                dir: 'rigt',
                h_loc: ['/pr/op'],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            eptt: 'yie[3:0:0]',
            remark: null,
            race: 'false',
            spt: ['mki[2:7:21]', 'epk[20:14.2:9.8]'],
            inod: 'u_pqp',
            mlace: 'pqp',
            portblair: ['qq[31:9:24]', 'ax[2:16:1]'],
            marcus: [
              {
                dir: 'left',
                h_loc: ['/op/locs'],
                sign: '0',
                portblair_width: '8',
                race_duty: '0',
              },
              {
                race_duty: '0',
                portblair_width: '8',
                sign: '2',
                dir: 'rigt',
                h_loc: ['/pr/op'],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      qq: 'ss',
    },
  },
  dst: 'dss',
};

// function to take out the mid_nest structure to change its remark key
function findJson(json) {
  var mid_ret = [];
  for (var k in json) {
    if (k === 'mid_nest') {
      //console.log("breaking as mid reached");
      mid_ret = json[k];
      break;
    } else if (typeof json[k] === 'object') {
      findJson(json[k]);
    }
  }

  console.log('--after break--');
  return mid_ret;
}

var mid_ret = findJson(nestedJson);
var remark_arr = ['remark_1', 'remark2']; // array for assigning remarks

for (var i in remark_arr) {
  var rem = remark_arr;
  mid_ret[i]['remark'] = rem;
}

// assigning the changed mid_ret back to the original nestedJson
for (var k in nestedJson) {
  if (k === 'mid_nest') {
    nestedJson[k] = mid_ret;
  } else if (typeof nestedJson[k] === 'object') {
    continue;
  }
}
```

However, the above code is not working as in the `findJson()` ,

(i)  even after matching the mid_nest the loop is not breaking, still iterating hence not returning the correct mid_nest value.

(ii) Because of that the rest of the processing like , changing the remark key by the array values and assigning it back to the original structure is not working.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: You may not find top and mid nest because `nestedjson` does not contain such keys.

Comment: @HMR Apologies, I corrected my JSON, could you pls tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems overly complex to me, although you will need to re-curse through your JSON. Take a look at this working example. This should simply set the `remark` value for `mid_nest` to `mid_nest_remark` and the `remark` value for `top_nest` to `tpo_nest_remark`. I'll let you tweak it yourself.

```js
var nestedjson = {
  edition: '1.3.0',
  OUTER_MOST: {
    secondnest: {
      mainstruct: {
        top_nest: [
          {
            portblair: 'mtlb_wc_way0_fcl',
            dir: 'left',
            locs: ['/loc/local'],
            remark: 'crc',
            id: 1544593588899,
            $count: 0,
            $parent: 0,
            $level: 1,
            $height: 256,
          },
        ],

        mid_nest: [
          {
            ept: 'qop[3:0:0]',
            remark: null,
            race: 'false',
            spt: ['mki[2:7:21]', 'epk[20:14.2:9.8]'],
            inod: 'u_pqp',
            mlace: 'pqp',
            portblair: ['qq[31:9:24]', 'ax[2:16:1]'],
            marcus: [
              {
                dir: 'left',
                h_loc: ['/op/locs'],
                sign: '0',
                portblair_w: '81',
                race_duty: '0',
              },
              {
                race_duty: '0',
                portblair_h: '28',
                sign: '2',
                dir: 'rigt',
                h_loc: ['/pr/op'],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            eptt: 'yie[3:0:0]',
            remark: null,
            race: 'false',
            spt: ['mki[2:7:21]', 'epk[20:14.2:9.8]'],
            inod: 'u_pqp',
            mlace: 'pqp',
            portblair: ['qq[31:9:24]', 'ax[2:16:1]'],
            marcus: [
              {
                dir: 'left',
                h_loc: ['/op/locs'],
                sign: '0',
                portblair_width: '8',
                race_duty: '0',
              },
              {
                race_duty: '0',
                portblair_width: '8',
                sign: '2',
                dir: 'rigt',
                h_loc: ['/pr/op'],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      qq: 'ss',
    },
  },
  dst: 'dss',
};

var remark_arr = ['remark_1', 'remark2'];

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var val = assignRemarks( nestedjson );
    console.log(val)
});

function assignRemarks(theObject) {
    var result = null;
    if(theObject instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
            result = assignRemarks(theObject[i]);
            if (result) {
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var prop in theObject) {
            if(prop == 'top_nest') {
              //set the remark property for top-nest here
              theObject[prop].forEach(x => x.remark = 'top_nest_remark')
            }
            if(prop == 'mid_nest') {
              for (let i = 0; i < theObject['mid_nest'].length; i++)
              {
                //set the remark property for mid-nest here
                theObject['mid_nest'][i].remark = remark_arr[i];
              }
            }
            if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
                result = assignRemarks(theObject[prop]);
            } 
        }
    }
    return theObject;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are assigning mid_nest_remarks to all the remark field under mid_nest whereas they should be populated one by one from an array,  Thanks

Comment: See the updated code which now gets the values from the array.